# QSlider with ticks not properly drawn

Tags: c++, qt, qslider

Enabling a ticks for QSlider seems to mess up the sizeHint of the slider itself.

Consider this simple code:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QSlider ds{Qt::Horizontal};

   ds.setRange(0, 100);
   ds.setTickPosition(QSlider::TicksAbove);
   ds.setTickInterval(20);
   ds.show();

   return a.exec();
}
```

and this is how is rendered:

[image]

notice how the slider is cropped below.

this behaviour is the same in a complex widget too of course:

[image]

Resizing the window of the first slider tick position does not follow the slider itself.

[image]

So the question is how have a QSlider rendered properly with ticks enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The practical way I found to solve this is to set the minimum size manually to the bare minumum to avoid the incorrect render:

```
ds.setMinimumHeight(30);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to add **VerticalSpacers** at the **top** and **bottom**, which are set to "**expanding**" So that the slider is sandwiched. So when you resize the whole widget, for vertical changes th slider stays **minimumHeight**, but for horizontal changes it expands (at least this is what I expect what you want to achieve).